# Upstart monitoring problems in ubuntu and creating a pid

Tags: ubuntu, pid, upstart

I was looking for how to create a pid file for monitoring of upstart processes in ubuntu. I looked at the accepted answer in [Ubuntu, upstart, and creating a pid for monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972023/ubuntu-upstart-and-creating-a-pid-for-monitoring) and ended up with following code:

```
env PROGRAM_NAME=myscript
env BASE_PATH=/bar/

respawn limit 5 30

script
${BASE_PATH}/bin/python ${BASE_PATH}/scripts/${PROGRAM_NAME}.py -e ${BASE_PATH}/foo.ini
end script

post-start script
echo PID=`status myscript | egrep -oi '([0-9]+)$' | head -n1` 
echo $PID > /var/run/${PROGRAM_NAME}.pid
end script

post-stop script
rm -f /var/run/${PROGRAM_NAME}.pid
end script
```

There are 3 problems I encounter:

1. Somehow this code creates two processes. The parent process (checked through ps -ef | grep python) is just a shell such as:

   ```
   /bin/sh -e -c ${BASE_PATH}/bin/python ${BASE_PATH}/scripts/${PROGRAM_NAME}.py -e ${BASE_PATH}/foo.ini /bin/sh
   ```

   While the child process has the correct substitutes:

   ```
   /bar/bin/python /bar/scripts/myscript.py -e /bar/foo.ini
   ```
2. The pid file contains the pid of the *parent* of the actual process. Not the child one which is the actual process.
3. The respawn doesn't work. I kill the child process with `kill pid` (which kills the parent too, but not vice versa).